# unable to save serialized data into wordpress db

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook

I am trying to save a group feed, from facebook in to my sql-database. I am using wordpress cms. The issue is I am unable to save serialized data obtained from facebook.

```
   require_once __DIR__. '/Facebook/autoload.php';
   /*API details */
   $response = $fb->get( '/xxxxxxxx/feed?fields=type,description,story&limit=1',
   $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken() 
   ); 
        $decoded = $response->getDecodedBody(); // because for me it is a better parsable format than a json feed.
        $string_data = serialize($decoded);
        //$string_data = serialize('lorem');

        ##### INSERT THE DATA INTO WORDPRESS
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 'groupFeed', 
                    array( 
                        'data' => $string_data,
                        'timestamp' => time()
                    )
                );
```

The data column remains blank. However if I try `$string_data = serialize('lorem')`, wordpress is able to save it as `s:5:"lorem";`. What do you think is the problem here ?

---

Here is an example result of var_dump($string_data);

```
string(1397) "a:2:{s:4:"data";a:1:{i:0;a:5: s:4:"type";s:6:"status";s:12:"created_time..
```

Comment: which Datatype of fields you make in DB , it should be text /

Comment: Type is varchar and length is 255, if that is the issue how come the test string is saved ?

Comment: You can use mediumtext or longtext as per my reply below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The varchar type can store only 255 Characters. You have to use the longtext or some other data type based on the charcters.

```
      Type | Maximum length
-----------+-------------------------------------
  TINYTEXT |           255 (2 8−1) bytes
      TEXT |        65,535 (216−1) bytes = 64 KiB
MEDIUMTEXT |    16,777,215 (224−1) bytes = 16 MiB
  LONGTEXT | 4,294,967,295 (232−1) bytes =  4 GiB
```

Note that the number of characters that can be stored in your column will depend on the character encoding.